# infusionsoft dsfind().Divide data into 3 chuncks in different pages

Tags: php, api, infusionsoft

data i am fetching from infusion using tag id and dsfind() function. and that data i have to divide into 3 pages. (data used be unique)

```html
    <?php

require("isdk.php");

$app = new iSDK;

if ($app->cfgCon("infusionid")) 
{
  $returnFields = array('Id','Email');
  $contacts = $app->dsFind('Contact',14,0,'Groups',7406,$returnFields);
  
  echo '<pre>', print_r($contacts), '</pre>';

}
?>
```

I want to print this series

```
     <tr>
        <td><?php echo $contacts[0]['Id'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $contacts[0]['Email']; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $contacts[4]['Id'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $contacts[4]['Email']; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $contacts[7]['Id'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $contacts[7]['Email']; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $contacts[11]['Id'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $contacts[11]['Email']; ?></td>
    </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use foreach() function e.g:

```
echo "<table>";
foreach ( $contacts as $var) {
         echo "<tr><td>ID: ", $var['Id']."</td>";
         echo "<td>Email: ", $var['Email']."</td></tr>";
    }
echo "</table>";
```